# Simplifying addition of three bits from using three half-adders

Tags: digital-logic, adder

I analysed using three half-adders to add three (same weight) binary digits.
I understood that the third half-adder's *and* gate will never give an output different from 0 so we used two half-adders and a gate.

I also noticed that the two carries could be (0 and 1 / 1 and 0 / 0 and 0) but they will never be 1 and 1.

My question is why we don't use an XOR gate instead of an OR gate?
[this photo clarifies if 3 half-adders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9xXw.jpg)

[this is where I want the XOR instead of OR gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmq1m.jpg)

[image: XOR instead of OR]

Comment: XOR or OR gate where? A schematic would clarify your question.

Comment: I edited my question with pictures but unfortunately the comments on the pictures aren't written I am so sorry for this it is the first time to ask on the website

Comment: Please try and tinker with the schematic editor from the post editor tool bar. There even is a half adder…

Comment: i added another one to clarify

Comment: (Good job on providing useful descriptions in the image references! And a clear diagram, too…)

Answer (score 1):

*Logically*, OR and EXOR gates are equivalent here.
Trying to build both from NAND or NOR gates, an OR gate looks much simpler needing 3 and 2 gates in 2 levels, respectively, where an EXOR needs 4 resp. 5 in 3 levels.

At the C-MOS/switch level, it doesn't look that bad, but uses 4 transistors/switches more.